# Variadic template implementation for callback functions

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement an abstraction, which can be used to store different types of callbacks where the argument type and number of arguments differ. I am facing compilation issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>

class Worker
{
    public:
        Worker()
        {
            
        }
        void DoSomething1(int data, const std::function<void(int, char, bool)> &aCallback)
        {
            std::thread([aCallback](){
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
                aCallback(10, 'A', true);
            }).detach();
        }
        
        void DoSomething2(int data, const std::function<void(std::string)> &aCallback)
        {
            std::thread([aCallback](){
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
                aCallback("HelloWorld");
            }).detach();
        }
};

template<class proxyclass_>
class ClientAbstraction
{
public:

  ClientAbstraction():mProxy(std::make_shared<proxyclass_>())
  {
  }
    
  std::shared_ptr<proxyclass_> operator->()
  {
    return mProxy;
  }
  
  template<typename... _attribs>
  void responseFunc(std::uint64_t aSequenceNumber, const _attribs&... Attributes)
  {
    typedef std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> Listener;
    Listener func = setResetListener(false, aSequenceNumber, (Listener) nullptr);
    if (func)
    {
      func(Attributes...);
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "could not find matching callback function " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
  }

  template<typename... _attribs>
  std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> setResetListener(bool isSet,
                                                           std::uint64_t aSeqNum,
                                                           std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> &&func)
  {
    typedef std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> Listener;
    static std::unordered_map<std::uint64_t, Listener> ListenerMap;

    if (isSet)
    {
      ListenerMap.insert(std::make_pair(aSeqNum, std::move(func)));
      return std::move(func);
    }
    else
    {
      auto it = ListenerMap.find(aSeqNum);
      Listener returnfunc = nullptr;
      if (it != ListenerMap.end())
      {
        returnfunc = nullptr;
      }
      return returnfunc;
    }
  }

  std::uint64_t mSeqNr;  
  
    
private:
    std::shared_ptr<proxyclass_> mProxy;
};

class Caller
{
public:
    Caller()
    {
        mWorker.setResetListener<int, char, bool>(true, ++mWorker.mSeqNr, 
            std::bind(&Caller::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1, 
            std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
    }
    
    void  callback(int, char, bool)
    {
        std::cout << "callback received\n"; 
    };
    
private:
    ClientAbstraction<Worker> mWorker;
};

int main()
{
    Caller c;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error while compiling.

```
Compilation failed due to following error(s).main.cpp:106:178: error: no matching function for call to ‘ClientAbstraction::setResetListener(bool, uint64_t&, std::_Bind_helper&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&, const std::_Placeholder<3>&>::type)’
         mWorker.setResetListener<int, char, bool>(true, ++mWorker.mSeqNr, std::bind(&Caller::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
                                                                                                                                                                                  ^
main.cpp:67:43: note: candidate: template std::function ClientAbstraction::setResetListener(bool, uint64_t, std::function&&) [with _attribs = {_attribs ...}; proxyclass_ = Worker]
   std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> setResetListener(bool isSet,
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:67:43: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:106:178: note:   ‘std::_Bind_helper&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&, const std::_Placeholder<3>&>::type {aka std::_Bind, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>))(int, char, bool)>}’ is not derived from ‘std::function’
         mWorker.setResetListener<int, char, bool>(true, ++mWorker.mSeqNr, std::bind(&Caller::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3));
```

Comment: Your code can be reduced to the following shorter example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fxqW1ssn6 (fixed)

Comment: @Frank, but the error is still there

Comment: Yes, but a smaller, simpler example makes it easier for potential answerers to help you. I wrote my comment mostly for their benefit.

Answer (score 1):

First step, stop using `std::bind`.  It requires a lot of expertise to get right, because it behave exceedingly complex ways in some corner cases.  And its error messages are crazy.

Write a lambda.

Second, `std::function` is a type erasure type.  Type erasure types are not a good plan for type deduction, because `std::bind` doesn't return it, lambdas are not them, and type deduction only works on exact type match, not on conversion.

So this is a design error:

```
template<typename... _attribs>
std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> setResetListener(bool isSet,
                                                       std::uint64_t aSeqNum,
                                                       std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> &&func)
```

if you expect `_attribs` to be deduced.

Third, taking it by `&&` is probably a bad idea.  Take it by value, and move-out of it.

It looks like your goal is to create a

```
 static std::unordered_map<std::uint64_t, Listener> ListenerMap;
```

for every set of arguments so you can get it out.  This is amazingly fragile and global data, and doing that in the middle of another function is a bad idea.  I can fix doing it in another function; make a single function

```
 template<class...Args>
 static std::unordered_map<std::uint64_t, std::function<void(Args const&...)>& getListenerMap() {
   static std::unordered_map<std::uint64_t, std::function<void(Args const&...)> ListenerMap;
   return ListenerMap;
 }
```

Now this gets rid of the "set or get" function nonsense.

`setResetListener` now starts with

```
auto& ListenerMap = getListenerMap<_attribs>();
```

and `responseFunc` can do the same without the `nullptr` nonsense.

We now clean up this:

```
template<class... Args>
void setListener(
  std::uint64_t aSeqNum,
  std::function<void(const Args&...)> func
)
```

there, much cleaner.

At call site:

```
mWorker.setListener<int, char, bool>(
  ++mWorker.mSeqNr, 
  [this](auto&&...args){
    this->callback(args...);
  }
);
```

so much simpler than the `bind` case.

Sadly, we aren't done.  This still doesn't compile.  At least the error message is a bit less noisy.

The easy way to clean this up is to block deduction on the 2nd argument of `setListner`.

```
template<class... Args>
void setListener(
  std::uint64_t aSeqNum,
  std::type_identity_t<std::function<void(const Args&...)>> func
)
```

and the deduction error goes away.

Pre [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can write your own `type_identity_t` like this:

```
template<class T>
struct id {using type=T;};
template<class T>
using id_t = typename id<T>::type;
```

and `id_t` does the same deduction blocking.

Your issue is that your types passed to `...` may or may not be final, and the compiler tries to deduce the full set of types, and cannot, because your argument isn't a std function.

Blocking deduction makes this problem go away.

Comment: This is what exactly, I want to achieve. The lambda may not be a solution always. https://onlinegdb.com/LjympgyZQ

Comment: @trilo there is no sane use of std bind that isn't easy to replace with a lambda.  The insane uses include passing bind to bind.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a C++ template expert, I just tried the following and it runs for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>

class Worker
{
 public:
    Worker()
    {

    }
    void DoSomething1(int data, const std::function<void(int, char, bool)>& aCallback)
    {
        std::thread([aCallback]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        aCallback(10, 'A', true);
        }).detach();
    }

    void DoSomething2(int data, const std::function<void(std::string)>& aCallback)
    {
        std::thread([aCallback]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        aCallback("HelloWorld");
        }).detach();
    }
};

template<class proxyclass_>
class ClientAbstraction
{
  public:

   ClientAbstraction() :mProxy(std::make_shared<proxyclass_>())
   {
   }

   std::shared_ptr<proxyclass_> operator->()
   {
      return mProxy;
   }

   template<typename... _attribs>
   void responseFunc(std::uint64_t aSequenceNumber, const _attribs&... Attributes)
   {
      typedef std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> Listener;
      Listener func = setResetListener(false, aSequenceNumber, (Listener) nullptr);
      if (func)
      {
          func(Attributes...);
      }
      else
      {
          std::cout << "could not find matching callback function " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
       }
    }

    template<typename... _attribs>
    std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> setResetListener(bool isSet,
    std::uint64_t aSeqNum,
    std::function<void(const _attribs&...)>&& func)
    {
       typedef std::function<void(const _attribs&...)> Listener;
       static std::unordered_map<std::uint64_t, Listener> ListenerMap;

       if (isSet)
       {
          ListenerMap.insert(std::make_pair(aSeqNum, std::move(func)));
          return std::move(func);
       }
       else
       {
          auto it = ListenerMap.find(aSeqNum);
          Listener returnfunc = nullptr;
          if (it != ListenerMap.end())
          {
             returnfunc = nullptr;
          }
          return returnfunc;
       }
     }

     std::uint64_t mSeqNr;


  private:
  std::shared_ptr<proxyclass_> mProxy;
};

class Caller
{
  public:
   Caller()
   {
      mWorker.setResetListener<Caller&, int, char, bool > (true, ++mWorker.mSeqNr, &Caller::callback);
   }

   void  callback(const int&, const char&, const bool&)
   {
     std::cout << "callback received\n";
   };

private:
   ClientAbstraction<Worker> mWorker;
};

int main()
{
  Caller c;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to accomplish something like this https://www.onlinegdb.com/LjympgyZQ